# Stackoverflow style data list view

Tags: asp.net, view, datalist

I'm beginner in `ASP.Net`.I'm know developing the small project for searching data from DB.
I use ASP.Net web form and ADO.Net.I would like to show the data list like stackoverflow because I don't want to use `GridView`.
I've some data fields to show example.

- Title
- Description
- Date
- Keyword

Please check out my screen shoot now I use `Literal` for draft.

[image]

so Please point to me what control I should use and that control will attach with `Pager` for the data list.

Important: Please let me know how to make layout template for the data list (Details)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Repeater

http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp

And if you need to page it

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/page-repeater-aspnet2-csharp.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you were a little more specific and explained what you've tried so far.

You can do this without using any control at all if you wish. In this case, you'll need to either create the output string and assign it to a Literal control or simply render it when the page renders by forming the markup directly to the response stream.

If on the other hand, you want to go ahead and use a control for this, a grid control may or may not make the most sense.

Comment: @Janathan let me know the way without control.I prefer that