# Adding pagination to a repeater

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to add pagination to a repeater to display say 5 items per page?

Answer (score 3):

Repeater doesn't have a built-in repeater support, but you can check this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/pagination_repeater.aspx

Anyways, I want to suggest you to check what ListView control can do for you in this area :)

Comment: If you have .NET 3.5+, I totally agree ListView is 10* better!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/page-repeater-aspnet2-csharp.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx

Duplicate?

[Stackoverflow style data list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710671/stackoverflow-style-data-list-view/4710750#4710750)